# Prove the following using Maclaurin's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Prove that
$$\log(1+e^x)=\log 2+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{8}x^2-\frac{1}{192}x^4......$$
I have tried doing it.
Tell me if you think the question is wrong

Comment: If you expand it using a Maclaurin series about $x = 0$ the first term is $\log(1+e^x)$ evaluated at $x = 0$, so $\log(1+e^0) = \log(2)$.

Comment: Well, in Maclaurin series the first term is $f(0)$, here it's $\log (1+e^0)=\log (2)$.

Comment: oh... thanks i got lost.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f (x) = \log (1 + e^x)$. Then the McLaurin series of $f (x)$ at $x = 0$ is $$f (x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)} (0)} {n!} x^n = \log 2+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{8}x^2 + \cdots$$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Maclaurin series states: $$f(x)=f(0)+\frac{x^1}{1!}f'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+\cdots + \frac{x^n}{n!}f^n(0)$$

What is $f(0)$ here?

Comment: log 2... yeah i got it

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

There is a shortcut which, may be, you could like. Consider $$y=\log(1+e^x) \implies y'=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

- replace $e^{-x}$ by its Taylor series at $x=0$
- perform the long division
- integrate each term without forgetting the integration constant
- adjust the integration constant